# Can I use 2 different inernet connections at the same time

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, proxy

I have a corporate internet connection available in ethernet and wi-fi. Also theres a regular connection available only as wi-fi.

Is there some way to keep connected to corporate internet connection due to having to work on domain sites and also use the other connection for unrestricted internet access. Currently when I connect via cable to corporate and wireless to other network, the proxy restrictions still apply.

I'm using windows 8

Comment: Maybe you are using an operating systems that let you choose at fork time which NIC has to be used by each process, maybe not.

Answer (score 2):

You could create a default route (0.0.0.0 = "Standard gateway) for your wireless network and add specific routes using the corporate network for intranet IPs.

http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows/adding-a-tcpip-route-to-the-windows-routing-table/

Comment: Wouldn't this affect my work domain? Would I still be able to connect to domain sites?

Comment: If you add specific routes using your corporate network for the domain sites everything _should_ work just fine.

Comment: I'll give this a try. Will return back with the results